# to fetch case insensitive word from a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Suppose, I am having a string like

```
$res = "there are many restaurants in the city. Restaurants like xyz,abc. one restaurant like.....";
```

In the above example, We can find `restaurant in 3 places`. I need the count to be `3`.

```
$pattern = '/Restaurant/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($res,10), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

One more problem
Which is related to the above question. i.e., I am having text like `Food & Drinks`. I need to match this word with `food` or `drinks` or `seafood`... etc. can anyone please help me in getting this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the modifier `i`, that is `/restaurant[s]{0,1}/i`

Comment: There are some contradictions in your post... Do you want the **entire** match to be case insensitive? Or only the first letter? Also, what about the last `s` in the word? Is that optional?

Comment: if I have a string like $res = "there are restaurants in the city. Restaurants like xyz,abc"; How can I find all the words which matches the restaurant. can i get the count of the matched pattern.\

Comment: @Gireesh - yes.. but what about a string like `ResTaurAnt`? Should that be matched as well?

Comment: yes, I have edited my question. please check that once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
$pattern = '/restaurants?/i';
```

There are two changes that I made to your original regex:

1. Adding the `i` modifier - this is the case insensitive flag.
2. Adding `s?` to the end of the search string. This makes the last `s` character optional. It matches zero or one occurances of `s`.

Note that because we are using the case insensitive flag, this regex will also match things like :

- ResTaurants
- rEstaurantS
- RESTauRANTS

Comment: It's not supposed to be case-insensitive. Only the first char should be insensitive.

Comment: @Pescis - this is not specifically what the OP stated. Although you could be right... Let's [wait and see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088917/to-fetch-case-insensitive-word-from-a-regular-expression#comment29929671_20088917)

Comment: OP clearly stated only four cases, whereas only the first letter is allowed to be upper-case. Well, it works for all those and even more so why not.

Comment: @Pescis - no... The actual quote is `"...cases like Restaurants or restaurant or restaurants..."`. *My understanding* was that this was a list of examples and not a list of all possible options...

Comment: @Pescis - looks like I was correct - see the OP's comment reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088917/to-fetch-case-insensitive-word-from-a-regular-expression#comment29929830_20088917)

Comment: @Pescis: The way I see it, we're not here to answer people's questions so much as to help them find the right questions to ask and how to ask them. :D

Comment: I am having some small problem which is related to the above question. i.e., I am having text like "Food & Drinks". I need to match this word with food or drinks or seafood... etc. can anyone please help me in getting this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Gireesh - If you have a new question, you'll be much better off just opening a new post. By posting it in a comment here, it's only me who will see it.

Answer (score 2):

The [`i`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier is used for case-insensitive matching. The [`?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) quantifier makes the preceding token optional matching in this case the preceding `s` either zero or one time.

You are using `preg_match()` wanting to get all  matches, you need [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$pattern = '/restaurants?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, substr($res,10), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/70278)

Comment: Also need to identify Restaurant from "Restaurants". Please help me in that

Comment: Sweeter than a fruit. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am having some small problem which is related to the above question. i.e., I am having text like "Food & Drinks". I need to match this word with food or drinks or seafood... etc. can anyone please help me in getting this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094107/match-a-string-or-substring-from-a-given-word-using-regex-php  .. new question. Plz help me

Comment: @Lix plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094107/match-a-string-or-substring-from-a-given-word-using-regex-php

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at a [regex guide](http://regex101.com/) - this is a very simple request.

`|` in regex means or and `?` means 0 or 1 of previous char or group, so the following pattern should work for your specification:

```
$pattern = '/[Rr]estaurants?/
```

Comment: Wrong, your regex will match only `R` in `Restaurant`. Should have tested it first with the tool you posted the link to...

Comment: @Havelock I surely meant to have the R's in a group. *hides*

Comment: Still, better use `[]` instead of `()` ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
  As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet

  $url = "http://www.examplesite.com/";
  $curl = new Curl();
  $res = $curl->get($url);
  $pattern = '/Restaurant(s)*/i';
  preg_match($pattern, substr($res,10), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
  print_r($matches);
```

Comment: This would also match `RestaurantQ`

Comment: This will match 'Restauran' and 'Restaurantttttttttttttttttttttttttttt' as well. Not even 'Restaurants'.

Comment: i need to match restaurant, from `Restaurantrrrr` or `aaaarestaurantrrrr`. It should match the word in all cases

Comment: Now it will for instance match `Restaurantssssssssssss` as well. `*` means the previous group (or char) infinity to 0 times. What you want is what the other answers have, `?`, which means 1 to 0 times.