# Match a string or substring from a given word using regex php

Tags: php, regex

I am having text like `Food & Drinks`. I need to match this word with `food` or `drinks` or `seafood`... etc. can anyone please help me in getting this. Thanks in advance.

```
$res = "campbell italian seafood. Italian Food of 2005 Award. Some drinks are very tasty";
$pattern = '/^((?!Food & Drinks).)*$/s';
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, substr($res,10), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
        echo ++$count;
    }else{
        echo $count;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your requirements are incredibly unclear. Give us some more example inputs and the desired matches.

Comment: is it possible to find a word `food` from `Food & Drinks`

Comment: do you want to find the number of times the words food OR drink occur in $res?

Comment: yes, that also ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example in the question, the following will match `seafood`, `Food` and `drinks`. :

```
/\w*(?:Food|Drinks)\w*/i
```

If you don't care about matching the whole word `seafood` - and just want to match the food part of it (which is all you need if you're just counting how many matches), you can simply use:

```
'/Food|Drinks/i'
```

I don't know where you're getting the string `Food & Drinks` from, or what the other possible search terms could look like, so I can only advise you for the specific example in the question. But to get from `Food & Drinks` to `Food|Drinks` you can use `str_replace`.

---

**Here is the example implemented in PHP:**

```
$str = 'Food & Drinks';
$terms = str_replace(' & ', '|', $str);

$res = "campbell italian seafood. Italian Food of 2005 Award. 
        Some drinks are very tasty";
$pattern = '/\w*(?:'.$terms.')\w*/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $res, $matches);

echo 'Count: '.count($matches[0]);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Count: 3
Array ( [0] => seafood [1] => Food [2] => drinks )
```